# How do I use format codes when adding text to a NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I have a NSTextview called 'output' and it is set to non editable. I use

```
[self.output setString:[self.output.string stringByAppendingString:@"My string"]];
```

to add text to it. My question is, how to I use format codes in it? Example

```
[self.output setString:[self.output.string stringByAppendingString:@"%d",myInt]];
```

This throws error : Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2.
Is there any way to do this without an error?

Comment: What you really want is `stringByAppendingFormat` not `stringByAppendingString `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is stringByAppendingFormat not stringByAppendingString.

```
[self.output setString:[self.output.string stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",myInt]];
```

Comment: This is probably a better way to do it. Thanks!